# How to implement multiple middlewares in vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a web app using vue.js 3 and vue-router. I followed this tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/vue-middleware-pipelines/
The above tutorial showed how to create middleware to prevent unauthorized access. They showed how to use multiple middleware to a single route. i.e.

```
children: [{
                path: '/dashboard/movies',
                name: 'dashboard.movies',
                component: Movies,
                meta: {
                    middleware: [
                        auth,
                        isSubscribed
                    ]
                }
            }],
```

If each middleware calls `next()` function one time, multiple middlewares calls it multiple time. But vue.js 3 documentation says to use `next()` function only one time. So how can I can use multiple middlewares in vue.js 3 as like the tutorial above?

Comment: It just means one middleware should call it once. It's fine if the function is called multiple times from different middlewares.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have problems implementing midlewares in Vue3, here's my solution:

```
// auth middleware
import { useAuthStore } from "@/stores/auth";

export default async function auth({ next }) {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();

  const user = await authStore.checkAuth();

  if (!( 'id' in user)) {
    console.log("Not logged in");
    return next({
      name: "Login",
    });
  }
  return next();
}
```

An other middleware:

```
// hasCity middleware
import { useCitiesStore } from "@/stores/cities";

export default function hasCity({ next }) {
  const citiesStore = useCitiesStore()

  if (!citiesStore.city) {
    console.log('City not selected')
    return next({
      name: 'CitySelector'
    })
  }
  return next();
}
```

And in router:

```
import auth from '@/middlewares/auth'
import hasCity from '@/middlewares/hasCity'

// other imports and code

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      layout: 'default',
      middleware: [auth, hasCity]
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login,
    meta: {
      layout: 'blank'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/city-selector',
    name: 'CitySelector',
    component: CitySelector,
    meta: {
      layout: 'blank'
    }
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  routes,
});

function nextFactory(context, middleware, index) {
  const nextMiddleware = middleware[index];
  
  if (!nextMiddleware){
    return context.next;
  }
  const subsequentMiddleware = nextFactory(context, middleware, index + 1);
  return nextMiddleware({ ...context, next: subsequentMiddleware })
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(!to.meta.middleware){
    return next();
  }

  const middleware = Array.isArray(to.meta.middleware)
    ? to.meta.middleware
    : [to.meta.middleware];
  const context = {
    to,
    from,
    next,
    router,
  };

  return middleware[0]({ ...context, next: nextFactory(context, middleware, 1) });

});

export default router;
```